# How do validation with thymeleaf and bean validation?

Tags: spring, validation, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I'm trying to perform a simple validation in my view, I know that the jsf it is very simple to do more in the spring mvc is giving me a headache ...
Can anyone help me with this validation? see what I'm doing wrong ??

my model

```
package br.com.nextinfo.multimedia.web.model;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.SequenceGenerator;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotBlank;

@Table
@Entity(name="slideshow")
public class SlideShow {

private Long condigo;

private String titulo;

private String subTitulo;

private ImagemSlider imagemSlider;


@Id 
@GeneratedValue(generator="codigo",strategy=GenerationType.AUTO) 
@SequenceGenerator(name = "codigo", sequenceName = "codigo_slideshow")    
@Column(name = "CODIGO")
public Long getCondigo() {
    return condigo;
}

@NotNull
@NotBlank
@Column(name = "TITULO" ,nullable = false)
public String getTitulo() {
    return titulo;
}
@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name ="CODIGO_IMAGEM")
public ImagemSlider getImagemSlider() {
    return imagemSlider;
}

@NotNull
@NotBlank
@Column(name = "SUBTITULO" ,nullable = false)
public String getSubTitulo() {
    return subTitulo;
}

public void setTitulo(String titulo) {
    this.titulo = titulo;
}

public void setSubTitulo(String subTitulo) {
    this.subTitulo = subTitulo;
}


public void setImagemSlider(ImagemSlider imagemSlider) {
    this.imagemSlider = imagemSlider;
}

public void setCondigo(Long condigo) {
    this.condigo = condigo;
}


}
```

my controller

```
package br.com.nextinfo.multimedia.web.controller;


import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.validation.Valid;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.RedirectAttributes;

import br.com.nextinfo.multimedia.web.model.ImagemSlider;
import br.com.nextinfo.multimedia.web.model.SlideShow;
import br.com.nextinfo.multimedia.web.services.AbstractFactoryService;
import br.com.nextinfo.multimedia.web.services.CreateSlideShowService;
import br.com.nextinfo.multimedia.web.services.ImagemServiceDatabase;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/arquivosbanco/")
public class FilesDatabaseController  implements AbstractControllerApp    ,PadraoCrudMetodos<ImagemSlider> {

@Autowired
private ImagemServiceDatabase imagemService;

@Autowired
private CreateSlideShowService slideShowService;

@Override
public String getRequisicaoPadrao(Model model) {
    List<ImagemSlider> lista = this.getAbstractService().realizaPaginacao("0", "10" ,null).getContent();
    model.addAttribute("listaObjetoPageStart", lista);
    model.addAttribute("img", new ImagemSlider());
    return this.getUrlInicial();
}

@Override
public String getUrlInicial() {
    return "arquivos/database/listarquivosbancodedados";
}

@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(value = "/img", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void showImage(@RequestParam("id") Long id, HttpServletResponse response,HttpServletRequest request)  throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("image/jpeg, image/jpg, image/png, image/gif");
    ImagemSlider imgdatabase =  imagemService.getAbstractService().getBean(id);
    if (imgdatabase!=null ) {
        response.getOutputStream().write(imgdatabase.getImage());
        response.getOutputStream().close();
    }
}

@Override
public AbstractFactoryService<ImagemSlider> getAbstractService() {
    return imagemService;
}
@RequestMapping(value = "/createslideshow/{imagemid}" ,method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String createslider(@PathVariable("imagemid") Long image,Model model){
    final ImagemSlider img  = this.imagemService.getBean(image);
    model.addAttribute("imgslider", img);
    model.addAttribute("slideshow", new SlideShow());

    return "arquivos/createdisplay";
}
@RequestMapping(value = "/save" ,method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String saveSlideShowr( @RequestParam Long imagemid ,@Valid  final SlideShow slideshow,final BindingResult result ,RedirectAttributes redirectAttrs){

    ImagemSlider img  = this.imagemService.getBean(imagemid);
    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        redirectAttrs.addFlashAttribute("org.springframework.validation.BindingResult.strategy", result);
        redirectAttrs.addFlashAttribute("slideshow", slideshow);
        return "redirect:/arquivosbanco/createslideshow/"+imagemid;
    }else{
        this.slideShowService.salva(slideshow);
        if (img != null) {
            slideshow.setImagemSlider(img);
            this.slideShowService.salva(slideshow);
        }
    }
    return this.getUrlInicial();
    }
  }

   <html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
    xmlns:layout="http://www.ultraq.net.nz/thymeleaf/layout"
    layout:decorator="/templates/layouts/principal">
    <head>
     <title>Criacao slideshow</title>
  </head>
 <body>

<div class="container-fluid" layout:fragment="corpopagina">
    <h3 class="page-header text-center">Criacao slide show</h3>

<form id="registration-form" class="form-horizontal"  th:object="${slideShow}" th:action="@{/arquivosbanco/save/?imagemid=}+${imgslider.codigo}"  method="post">

 <!-- Print all errors here!-->
<div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12">
    <div class="thumbnail">
        <img class="img-responsive" th:attr="src=@{'/upload/img?codigo='+${imgslider.codigo}}" width="400" height="400" />
        <span  class="text-center"></span>
        </div>  
        <div class="caption">
            <h5>Codigo <span th:text="${imgslider.codigo}" class="badge" style="margin-left:20px">5</span></h5>
            <h5>Nome <span th:text="${imgslider.nome}" class="badge" style="margin-left:20px">5</span></h5>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8 col-xs-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-xs-3 control-label">Titulo principal</label>
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="titulo"  /> 
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-xs-3 control-label">Sub titulo</label>
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control input-xs" name="subTitulo" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-actions">
                <label class="col-md-3 control-label"></label>
                <div class="col-md-7">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-large">Salvar</button>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-1"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
</body>
```

in my controller is validating usually more in view does not show anything how can I solve?

I am quite some time on stackoverflow, most can not find the solution ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your view is not showing anything as you have not included the error messages in your template. Here is an example below.

```
 <td th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('age')}" th:errors="*{age}">Name Error</td>
```

Comment: Check the following link for a working example http://spring.io/guides/gs/validating-form-input/

Comment: I tried to replicate what is already in the article, more does not work !!
If I put you mentioned take an expensive error, That should be easy to do, since the jsf and very simple ..
if you put it here
  <p th: if = "$ {# fields.hasErrors ('slideShow')}" th: errors = "* {slideShow}"> Name Error </ p> The error appears
Error:  Invalid property 'slideshow' of bean class [br.com.nextinfo.multimedia.web.model.SlideShow]: Bean property 'slideshow' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?

Comment: If you're using the Maven project, can you please show the POM.xml file?